# Godai's degree duration in terms of years

Tags: maison-ikkoku

I wanted to know the duration of the degree of godai of maison ikkoku as it happened in anime by number of years.
Like it was of 4 or 5 years?
Mainly I am confirmed that it was a 6 year plot but not on godai's degree.Please if someone could confirm that for me.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! If Godai said that the plot lasted for six years, then is there a reason you doubt him?

Comment: I mean I don't doubt that he said for almost six years he was in love.
It's just that I am not sure how long his degree went.like bachelor's is four years right so how six years?

Comment: And if six years is what it is then can you tell me the duration of his degree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean how long Godai attended college? Then he didn't repeat any year, so it was 4 years, the standard duration of college degree in Japan (which was modelled on US).

You can see [this](http://pingshan.parfait.ne.jp/maison/nenpyo1.html) for the timeline of the manga version. I've never seen the anime as a whole, but [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%81%E3%81%9E%E3%82%93%E4%B8%80%E5%88%BB) says Godai got a job right after graduation (while in manga there was an interval), so that there is about a year difference between manga and anime.

Comment: So if it's 4 years which I also thought then why did godai said in the movie that he had been loving her for 6 years

Comment: Oh so I see the manga and anime timelines are different.He proposed to kyoko after he graduated while in manga there was 2 years that's why he said 6 years.Also in manga he taught yagami after he graduated which was not the case in anime.

Comment: Therefore the plot in the anime lasted for 4 years when he proposed kyoko and if we count the birth of his daughter then 5 years